# Arreglar diagrama físico con tablas dinámica y recursiva

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Hice un diagrama físico de acuerdo al siguiente texto:

*Basándose en las reglas de normalización, cree en un diagrama físico de datos el diseño de una base de datos para el siguiente planteamiento:*

*Una  escuela  de  Tae  Kwon Do,  desea  lleva  el  control de  sus  alumnos, así  como los  exámenes  que estos presentan para obtener los grados correspondientes.*

*Un alumno está inscrito en un grupo, el cual pertenece a un turno y a unos de los planteles que la escuela tiene en los municipios.*

*Los exámenes se programan para un plantel, en una fecha y hora específicas.*

*En un examen pueden estar incluidos muchos alumnos, aunque estos pertenezcan a diferentes grados.*

*Para cada alumno en un examen se desea saber el grado que actualmente tienen, así como el grado para el cual presentarán examen.*

*No todos los alumnos asisten al examen, ya que este es opcional, así que se desea saber si el alumno llegó o no al examen, si llegó se desea saber si aprobó o no.*

*Un examen es aplicado o supervisado por uno de los maestros.Los datos del alumno son nombre, apellidos, dirección, teléfono, matricula, numero de chip, plantel, grado actual.*

*Los datos del maestro son nombre, apellidos, teléfono, turno y grado actual.*

*Nota:  Los  grados  además  de  tener  un  nombre  tiene  dos  datos  adicionales  que  son  el  color1  y  el color2 de la cinta que porta el alumno.**

Mi diagrama quedó de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero siento que quedó mal de alguna forma, y mis dudas respecto a esto es en los siguientes enunciados del texto:

***Los exámenes se programan para un plantel, en una fecha y hora específicas.***

***En un examen pueden estar incluidos muchos alumnos, aunque estos pertenezcan a diferentes grados.***

¿Cómo se podría representar de forma correcta lo anterior?
No sé exactamente si la tabla "Examen" es dinámica o no porque tiene una llave primaria.

Exactamente no sé cómo puedo representar el "grado siguiente" en este diagrama, yo tengo en mente que al ser "grado" y "grado siguiente" lo mismo, sería una tabla recursiva, pero, en uno de los enunciados pide el "grado siguiente" :

***Para cada alumno en un examen se desea saber el grado que actualmente tienen, así como el grado para el cual presentarán examen.***

¿Es necesario crear otra tabla para "grado siguiente" o hay una forma distinta de hacerlo?

Fuera de esto, creo estar bien, pero desearía que me pudieran corregir en la posibilidad de haya, por favor.

Comment: Si ya tienes el `id_grado` en Maestro y Alumno, no estaría redundante en Examen?

Comment: No son redundantes porque el grado del alumno se refiere al actual y el de Maestro no necesariamente tiene que ser el mismo que la del alumno. Por otro lado, la tabla de alumno debería ser un Maestro de Alumnos y en este no debería tener el grupo porque no es un atributo específico del alumno sino de la matrícula. El grado no debe tener grado siguiente sino requisitos. El o los grados que debes tener para acceder a este. Al menos es mi punto de vista.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: buen día amigo, tu pregunta tiene varios problemas: me parece que esta basada en opiniones (como lo harían ustedes); tambien veo que la pregunta esta relacionada a base de datos, pero no plantea un problema en su codificación, el problema planteado esta relacionado a diseño y arquitectura, tu pregunta iría mejor https://dba.stackexchange.com/, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ o https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me he permitido hacer un esquema entidad/relación y modelo relacional.

Este ultimo te indicara como hacer tu grafico.

Aquí te dejo el relacional en texto:

```
Alumno: Matricula, nombre, apellidos, direccion, telefono, chip, id_grupo, id_grado

Grupo: id, nombre

Grado: id, nombre, color1, color2, id_grado_next

Municipio: id, nombre

Plantel: id, nombre, id_municipio

Turno: id, matutino, dia_semana, id_grupo, id_plantel

Profesor: id, nombre apellido, telefono, id_grado

Profesor-turno: id, id_profesor, id_turno

Examen: id, presente, grado_actual, grado_next, aprobado, matricula, fecha, hora, id_plantel, id_profesor
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He usado los datos que facilitas en tu enunciado, aun así he notado que `turno` le faltaría un campo, yo lo he puesto, si consideras que no es acorde a las peticiones, no lo pongas.

Como peculiaridad del grafico, existe una única relación reciproca (`grado`) y una N:M entre `profesor` y `turno`

Para cualquier aclaración comenta.

---

Observa que te faltan relaciones, como el profesor y el horario

Answer (score 1):

Voy a expresar mi interpretación sobre los enunciados en los que tienes dudas. Aunque no creo despejar definitivamente tus dudas, (Sobre todo, al no utilizar notación estandar para diagramas ER, a mi me surgen un par también) algo de perspectiva debería ser de ayuda igualmente:

**Los exámenes se programan para un plantel, en una fecha y hora específicas.**
A mi entender esto ya está representado en el diagrama de manera adecuada.

**En un examen pueden estar incluidos muchos alumnos, aunque estos pertenezcan a diferentes grados.**
Esto va bastante enlazado con el tercer enunciado:

**Para cada alumno en un examen se desea saber el grado que actualmente tienen, así como el grado para el cual presentarán examen.**

No estoy familiarizado con el taekwondo, pero a mi parecer, el enunciado da a entender que los alumnos pueden presentarse a un grado que ellos consideren, y que no tiene porque seguir un orden especifico.

Dicho esto, en mi opinión, es que lo has complicado más de la cuenta con la tabla recursiva. Aunque es una opción válida, cabe preguntarse; ¿Es realmente necesaria en este caso?

Dada mi interpretación, yo considero más adecuado tener un campo id_grado en la tabla alumno, y otro campo grado_examen en la tabla examen que indica a qué grado se está presentando cada alumno.

Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Es necesario la recursión, pues después de cinturón blanco sigue blanco - amarillo, y solo lo sabes haciendo la recursión , indicando cual es el siguiente grado.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que hay cosas en tu diagrama que pueden mejorar. En primer lugar, la entidad **Resultado_Examen** no tiene mucho sentido tomando en cuenta que hay una relación de n a n (muchos a muchos) entre la tabla de examenes y alumnos. Por lo tanto, es más conveniente añadir un campo booleano que indique si el alumno estuvo presente en el examen y un campo booleano nulleable que indique si aprovó.
En segundo lugar, no hace falta esa tabla recursiva, tomando en cuenta que ya se sabe el grado del alumno (inherente en la relación) y solamente se necesita saber qué examen dará (tomando en cuenta que un hay un examen específico para ese grupo). Por esa razón con las ya existentes relación entre exámen y grupo y relación entre alumno y grupo, ese punto está resulto